# Where (in Germany) is the landscape behind this newsreader, with a gazebo on a small, lush steep hill surrounded by higher, broader forested hills?

Tags: germany, identify-this, photography

When the German *tagesschau* evening news on the public broadcaster *Arbeitsgemeinschaft der öffentlich-rechtlichen Rundfunkanstalten der Bundesrepublik Deutschland* (ARD) announce the upcoming weather forecast, there is the image of a landscape somewhere in Germany behind the announcer.

[image: Screenshot of a TV broadcast showing a newsreader. Behind the newsreader is a green, hilly landscape including a steep, lush hill with what appears to be a gazebo on its summit, and higher, forested hills in the background. There are some low clouds above the valley floor, with the sky above the clouds blue. The bottom third of the image is covered by a semi-transparent overlay showing the date, the word Wettervorhersage, and the label for the tagesschau TV broadcast. The logo for the Hessische Rundfunk (HR) is in the top left of the image.]
*Source: tagesschau broadcast on Hessische Rundfunk, broadcast 2021-11-22 20:00-20:15*

Usually, when faced with an unknown landscape, I tend to find it using reverse image search on Google Search.  However, in this case the reverse image search comes up with newsreaders with (different) landscapes behind them, which is reasonably impressive from a technical point of view, but not helpful to identify where this specific photo is located.

Where is this landscape with a steep, lush hill with a gazebo on the summit, surrounded by broader, forested hills?  Due to its appearance behind the newsreader on ARD *tagesschau* on German federal public television, I infer it is likely in Germany.  Usually German landscapes I can't identify are in Saxony (*Sachsen*), but I don't know if that is the case here too.

Comment: Hint: crop the image to include only the relevant part.

Comment: @jcaron I did the same with a arial city view with meme text on it.  Google correctly recognized it being Orlando California seen from the west.  I was suitably impressed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is [**Are Castle** (Burg Are)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_Castle) at [**Altenahr**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altenahr). Camera position is NE of the Castle. I'm not sure about the exact camera position, but the place is Are Castle for sure:

[image: Burg Are und Gymnch Porz, by Axel Hindemith, Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons]
<sup>Source: Axel Hindemith, Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Comment: What's that "umbrella" at the top?

Comment: That's no umbrella; that's a flying saucer.  Well, maybe not.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is simply a covered viewing platform where the keep once stood.

Comment: As an aside, that's [one of the hardest hit towns in the 2021 flooding](https://www.dw.com/en/flooding-in-germany-before-and-after-images-from-the-ahr-and-eifel-regions/a-58299008). (You know it's bad when the flood rips out the flood gauges.)

Comment: I think the camera is positioned here: https://goo.gl/maps/q9ih6PDqnJTcpykH9

Comment: @WGroleau: it's a hovering micro-pyramid. Ancient Egyptian technology at its finest!